# Replacing the content of a div by new database information without reloading the total page

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I need your help and really give thank to you for helping me.
I have a php page .That have 3 main div .Header ,footer ,content. Content contain another div question.

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div id="question">
   <form action="submitmysites.php">
       some input form  here 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">

 </div>
</div>
```

Now when the submit button clicked after performing the task of the form I want to reload the form's internal input with some new value.But do not want to reload the whole page .Because it waste net Bandwidth. If there is core JavaScript code it will be convenient to me rather than jQuery.Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: you need AJAX. Even though you don't want to look at jQuery, take a close look at it (jquery.com) and particularly its AJAX capability (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) And, just in case you're thinking about developing your own AJAX routines in javascript, save yourself the pain. Just use jQuery.

Comment: Take a look to "PHP and Ajax" on Google. You can do it using only Javascript, but Jquery will be faster for your development.

Comment: But will not the jquery.js file make slow to load the whole site loading at first time again and again ? @VincentDecaux

Comment: Both are telling the correct way.  Absolutely you need a ajax for changing the content without reload the whole page.

Comment: Yes you should use AJAX to achieve that.

Comment: @HamdunSoft Load Jquery file with CDN. It will be cached by the navigators and with Gzip, it weighs 25 kb.

Comment: @VincentDecaux thanks.I have get a way with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** when you post something, try to provide more details of:

- What do you need?
- What you try? Yes, you need to try first and post details about that.
- What error you get?

I said that because stack overflow users are not a "script storage". We try help you with your problem. But you not have a problem, you have a **requisition**.

So please, don't do that anymore.

### Solution

In the example below I call some page, get the result and write in the `#question` div.

So: **html result** (but is a php page, and you can do anything inside).

But you can get `json` result, change the method type request (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, etc). For more examples visit the jquery api:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

#### Form page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Template</h1>
        <div id="question">
            <form action="page.php" method="post">
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).parent().prop('action'),
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $('#question').html(data);
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Ajax Page

```
<h2>Ajax Page</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, minima, eligendi, ea atque nobis voluptatibus ut rerum consequuntur autem temporibus assumenda incidunt a sit. Voluptatem, dolores, assumenda expedita nam placeat distinctio sit non quae! Corrupti, deserunt, quisquam expedita omnis est aut quibusdam odit similique porro nostrum id natus quo fugiat nemo deleniti! Totam, illo, numquam mollitia repellat nihil praesentium dolore odio adipisci maiores excepturi vitae nisi libero cupiditate alias quam dignissimos quas corporis aspernatur deleniti quo modi? Accusamus, officia, repellendus, voluptates perspiciatis totam ea quae eius illo maiores corporis sint ratione doloribus quisquam vero vitae quos nemo officiis nam necessitatibus sit.</p>
```

#### Screenshots

[image: index - template page]

[image: index - template page - with ajax requisition]

Comment: I have got an idea. By applying will the whole page reload? Thanks @Patrick Maciel

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correctly answer as "solved".

Answer (score 0):

Loading new data without re-loading the whole page is done with the XMLHttpRequest object. However, if you encounter browser compatibility issues (i.e. support any old browser, ie? ..) jQuery would certainly help.

A simple example code in (german) wikipedia is at:
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

(This also already addresses incompatibility issues)

Comment: can you give me some link for tutorial . I have googled but all I seen they learning sites but few are tutorial. @fast

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a page created for each question you want to cycle through you can use jQuery, even though you don't want to, it's much easier and hassle free, to grab a file and throw it into your div. You would have to give your form the id attribute with an id. You can try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#FormID").on("submit", function(){

    $.get("path/filename", function(data){
       $("#question").html(data);
    });
});
});
```

It is untested, but I don't see an issue with it.